# Link to start my workflow doesn't appear on my list

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-workflow

I have already create my workflow on SharePoint designer and publish it to my SharePoint library so the Column which has the workflow name was added but the link to start my workflow(has the name of my first step) doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit vague but the column in the list simply shows the status of the workflow. To kick off the workflow manually, you need to go to the library and select the item you want to kick the workflow off for. In the ribbon, there is an option to go to workflow settings and in that page you will have the option to start the workflow. If you have correctly built the workflow this should run it. You left important information out of your request such as what version of SharePoint, what triggers your workflow, etc.. so this is the best I can do with that. If that does not solve the issue, I would suggest providing more information. Not many people will take any time to do guess work.